# Extract paragraph separated with *** using AWK

Tags: shell, text-processing, sed, awk, grep

I have a file like below:

```
blablabla
blablabla
***
thingsIwantToRead1
thingsIwantToRead2
thingsIwantToRead3

blablabla
blablabla
```

I want to extract the paragraph with `thingsIwantToRead`. When I had to deal with such a problem, I used [AWK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) like this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS="Separator above the paragraph"; RS="" } {print $2}' $file.txt | awk 'BEGIN{ FS="separator below the paragraph"; RS="" } {print $1}'
```

And it worked.

In this case, I tried to put `FS="***"`, `"\*{3}"`, `"\*\*"`
(it is not working because AWK treats it like a normal asterisk), `"\\*\\*"` or whatever regex I could think of, but it's not working (it's printing nothing).

Do you know why?

If not, do you know another way to deal with my problem?

Below an extract of the file I want to parse:

```
13.2000000000     , 3*0.00000000000       ,  11.6500000000     , 3*0.00000000000       ,  17.8800000000

Blablabla

  SATELLITE EPHEMERIS
     ===================
Output frame: Mean of J2000

       Epoch                  A            E            I           RA           AofP          TA      Flight Ang
*****************************************************************************************************************
2012/10/01 00:00:00.000     6998.239     0.001233     97.95558     77.41733     89.98551    290.75808    359.93398
2012/10/01 00:05:00.000     6993.163     0.001168     97.95869     77.41920    124.72698    274.57362    359.93327
2012/10/01 00:10:00.000     6987.347     0.001004     97.96219     77.42327    170.94020    246.92395    359.94706
2012/10/01 00:15:00.000     6983.173     0.000893     97.96468     77.42930    224.76158    211.67042    359.97311
 <np>
 ----------------
 Predicted Orbit:
 ----------------

 Blablabla
```

And I want to extract:

```
2012/10/01 00:00:00.000     6998.239     0.001233     97.95558     77.41733     89.98551    290.75808    359.93398
2012/10/01 00:05:00.000     6993.163     0.001168     97.95869     77.41920    124.72698    274.57362    359.93327
2012/10/01 00:10:00.000     6987.347     0.001004     97.96219     77.42327    170.94020    246.92395    359.94706
2012/10/01 00:15:00.000     6983.173     0.000893     97.96468     77.42930    224.76158    211.67042    359.97311
```

And the command I tried to use to get the numbers after the line of *'s:

```
`awk 'BEGIN{ FS="\\*{2,}"; RS="" } {print $2}' file | awk 'BEGIN{ FS="<np>"; RS="" } {print $1}'`
```

Comment: Are there `***` after the target paragraph?

Comment: No. In the real file, there is a line containing <np> or ^L depending on the editor I use (nedit or vi), and I dont know what this means...

Comment: So, what part of the file do you want to extract? Are the slashes (at the beginning of the `*` and `--` lines) actually part of the line? Do you want the data between `****` and `<np>`? Or until the next blank line?

Comment: Sorry no baskslashes, I added them when the text was not in a code block and forgot to remove them. Should be ok now, thanks.

Comment: The file is generated by a routine I have no knowledge of, and depending on the editor I use there is either <np> (with nedit) or ^L (with vi, or less) after the paragraph I want to extract (the numbers after the * line and before <np>), so I don't know how to deal with it......

Comment: What? So does a literal `<np>` in the file you wish to edit delimit the end of the paragraph - or is it a blank line instead? If you don't know the answer to that question then you have asked the wrong question. You need to first ask: *What the hell is <np> anyway?*

Comment: The first problem I encountered was the **** line. The <np> comes after. I don't think it's a literal <np>, it must mean something else.

Comment: @JoVe please show us your desired output. It really isn't clear from your description. Make sure to put it in a code block.

Comment: OK, see updated answer.

Comment: How many paragraphs (or `***` separated sections) are are we expected to expect to be in your output?

Comment: Also, are `***` separated sections always terminated by a `<np>` line?

Comment: There is only one paragraph to extract, the one between the line of *'s and the `<np>` line (special character I dont know the meaning of). But I need to parse different files of the same type as the file I put as an example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tell awk to print between the two delimiters. Specifically:

```
awk '/\*{4,}/,/<np>/' file
```

That will also print the lines containing the delimiters, so you can remove them with:

```
awk '/\*{4,}/,/<np>/' file | tail -n +2 | head -n -1
```

Alternatively, you can set a variable to true if a line matches the 1st delimiter and to false when it matches the second and only print when it is true:

```
awk '/\*{4,}/{a=1; next}/<np>/{a=0}(a==1){print}' file
```

The command above will set `a` to 1 if the current line matches 4 or more `*` and will also skip to the `next` line. This means that the `***` line will never be printed.

---

*This was in answer to the original, misunderstood, version of the question. I'm leaving it here since it can be useful in a slightly different situation.*

First of all, you don't want `FS` (field separator), you want `RS` (record separator). Then, to pass a literal `*`, you need to escape it twice. Once to escape the `*` and once to escape the backslash (otherwise, awk will try to match it in the same way as `\r` or `\t`). Then, you print the 2nd "line":

```
$ awk -vRS='\\*\\*\\*' 'NR==2' file

thingsIwantToRead1   
thingsIwantToRead2   
thingsIwantToRead3
```

To avoid the blank lines around the output, use:

```
$ awk -vRS='\n\\*\\*\\*\n' 'NR==2' file
thingsIwantToRead1   
thingsIwantToRead2   
thingsIwantToRead3
```

Note that this assumes a `***` after *each* paragraph, not only after the first one as you show.

Comment: @mikeserv because the title states "paragraph separated by `***`" and because the output only shows the first set of lines. Since the OP refers to it as "the paragraph after `***`", I assumed that the `***` was between each paragraph.  If that's not the case, the OP can use fredtantini's very good answer.

Comment: The way I was doing it, I treated the entire file as one record (hence the RS=""), and I used FS to read the paragraph I want (read as a field by awk). It worked until I had to deal with a "******" separator. Do you know why ? Even when I double escape the * it's not working. 
Your solution looks quicker though : can you explain how is it working ? I am not familiar with the -vRS option.

Comment: @JoVe the `-v` lets you set a variable. For example `awk -v g="foo" 'BEGIN{print g}` will return `foo` since that's the value of the variable `g`. I just wrote it with no space and used it to set the `RS` variable. What `******`? I don't see that in your example. If you show us the actual file you are trying to parse (including this problematic `******`), I can update my answer.

Comment: I edited my post : I put an extract of the file and an example of the awk command I used.

Comment: @JoVe please use the [formatting tools](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format your post. Just paste it directly into your question, select it and then hit the `{}` button.

Comment: @mikeserv why? To avoid the quoting issues?

Comment: It's mostly a hunch, actually, but [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208056/escape-sequences-passed-as-args-to-gawk-not-interpreted/208058#comment352123_208058) is all I know about it. I dunno if `awk` does anything with `*` as it does for `\t`, really. But according to that `ENVIRON` is one of only two ways to hand it string literals.

Comment: Thanks for the edited answer, but there are still a few problems left.
 `awk '/\*{4,}/,/<np>/' file` is not working but `awk '/\*\*\*\*/,/<np>/' file` works, why ?
<np> seems to be a special character, it is not recognized by awk. But I can parse until "Predicted orbit" and remove the last 3 lines.

Comment: By the way - the `tail|head` thing doesn't work for anything but the first paragraph - it still prints `***\n.*\n<np>` for all but the first paragraph.

Comment: @JoVe huh? What is `<np>`? Is that an actual `<`, `n`, `p` and `>` or is it supposed to represent something else? There's nothing special about it. It's possible that your `awk` flavor/version doesn't support `{N,}` but I can't know since you haven't told us anything about it. What OS are you on?

Comment: @mikeserv I'm a beginner in all this, so instead of reacting like that, tell me what is stupid in my question so I can learn. In my beginner's head, \\*{4,} not working can happen because of 2 things: either it does not recognize \* (so I tested it to be sure it recognizes it) or {4,} is not working and I find it strange. How is that stupid ?? Anyway it's not important.
To Terdon: Well it's not a <, n, p and >, it is supposed to represent something else but I dont know what. Again, it's not important. 
Sorry to have wasted your time and thank you for your help !

Comment: @JoVe  - your question isn't *stupid* - those are the good questions - it's *misleading*. I told you before, you're asking the wrong one - you can't be helped if you ask a question which does not apply to you. And if the data that you ask others to help you edit, is not *actually your data* then everyone has wasted their time. Do you see what I mean? That's why I said you need to start with asking - *What the hell is <np>?* - just like terdon just did.

Comment: @mikeserv Yes I understand. I'll do better next time. ;) I've get round the problem of <np> by doing this: `'/\*\*/ {parse=1; next} /^[^2]/ {parse=0} parse==1 {print}' file`. Thanks again !

Comment: @JoVe OK, so, presumably, your `<np>` is actually "lines that don't begin with a `2`" (that's what you're matching, anyway). Could you please [accept](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) one of the answers by clicking on the check mark to the left? That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to @terdon's answer, with awk (and sed) you can use range pattern:

```
awk '/sep1/,/sep2/{print}' file
```

or

```
sed -n '/sep1/,/sep2/p' file
```

will print everything (including) `sep1` and `sep2`. That is:

```
~$ awk '/sep1/,/sep2/{print}' file
sep1
thingsIwantToRead1
thingsIwantToRead2
thingsIwantToRead3
sep2
```

In your case:

```
~$ awk '/\*\*\*/,/^$/{print}' file
***
thingsIwantToRead1
thingsIwantToRead2
thingsIwantToRead3
```

Then you might want to delete the first and last line.

For instance with:

```
~$ sed -n '/\*\*\*/,/^$/p' file | sed '1d;$d'
thingsIwantToRead1
thingsIwantToRead2
thingsIwantToRead3
```

or

```
~$ awk '/\*\*\*/,/^$/{print}' file | awk 'NR>1&&!/^$/ {print}'
thingsIwantToRead1
thingsIwantToRead2
thingsIwantToRead3
```

If your paragraph isn't too long.

Answer (score 4):

With `sed` there are two ways to go with this. You can select *inclusively* or *exclusively*. In your case, an *inclusive* selection means printing all lines beginning with a match for `'^*\*\*'` up to and including one of either `^ *<np>` *(whatever that is)* or `^$` a blank line.

An *inclusive* selection can be specified with any of the range expressions  demonstrated in the other answers and involves specifying a *start printing here* pattern through to a *all the way through here* pattern.

An *exclusive* selection works in the opposite way. It specifies a *stop printing before here* pattern through to a *start printing after here* pattern. For your example data - and allowing for a *stop printing before here* pattern which will match either of a blank-line *or* that `<np>` thing:

```
sed -e 'x;/^\( *<np>.*\)*$/,/^*\** *$/c\' -e '' <infile >outfile
```

- `x`

  - Swaps hold and pattern spaces. This institutes a *look-behind* - `sed` is always one-line behind input - and the first line is always blank.
- `/^\( *<np>.*\)*$/`

  - This selects a *stop printing before here* line that matches from head to tail zero or more occurrences in the match group. Two kinds of lines can match zero or more occurrences of that - either a blank line or one with any number of *<spaces>* at the head of the line followed by the string `<np>`.
- `/^*\** *$/`

  - This selects a *start printing after here* line which opens with at least one `*` asterisk character and continues to the end of the line with only zero or more occurrences of the `*` asterisk and possibly closed by any number of spaces.
- `c\' -e ''`

  - This `c`hanges the entire blocked selection to a single blank line, squeezing all unwanted lines to the string *`EOF`*.

So any number of lines occurring before `^*\** *$` and after the first following `^\( *<np>.*\)*$` are always squeezed down to only a single blank, and only the first occurring paragraph *after* a match for `^*\** *$` is printed to stdout. It prints...

```
2012/10/01 00:00:00.000     6998.239     0.001233     97.95558     77.41733     89.98551    290.75808    359.93398
2012/10/01 00:05:00.000     6993.163     0.001168     97.95869     77.41920    124.72698    274.57362    359.93327
2012/10/01 00:10:00.000     6987.347     0.001004     97.96219     77.42327    170.94020    246.92395    359.94706
2012/10/01 00:15:00.000     6983.173     0.000893     97.96468     77.42930    224.76158    211.67042    359.97311
```

That assumes you want to handle any number of occurrences of the paragraph pattern in input. If you only want the *first* however, provided you have GNU `grep` and that *`infile`* is a regular, *lseekable* file:

```
{   grep -xm1 '*\** *'        >&2
    sed -n '/^\( *<np>.*\)*$/q;p'
}   <infile 2>/dev/null >outfile
```

... will work as well.

And actually, I guess, there are *three* ways. The third might look like:

```
sed 'H;$!d;x;s/\(\n\*\** *\n\(\([0-9./: ]*\n\)*\)\)*./\2/g'
```

...which reads in the whole file and then globally substitutes away every character which doesn't fall within the specifications of the matched lines. It prints the same as before, but those are a pain to write, and they're only safe performance-wise when you balance the optionals against *any* character.

Answer (score 1):

### Updated version based on question's edit:

Using Perl:

```
< inputfile perl -0777 -pe 's/.*[*]+\n(.*) <np>\n.*/$1/s' > outputfile
```

- `< inputfile`: redirects the content of `inputfile` to `perl`'s `stdin`
- `-0777`: forces Perl to slurp the whole file at once instead of line by line
- `-p`: forces Perl to print the lines
- `-e`: forces Perl to read a line of program from the arguments
- `> outputfile`: redirects the content of `perl`'s `stdout` to `outputfile`

**Regex breakdown**:

- `s`: asserts to perform a substitution
- `/`: starts the search pattern
- `.*[*]+\n`: matches any number of any character up to the end of a string ending with one or more `*` character immediately followed by a newline character
- `(.*) <np>`: matches and groups any number of any character up to any character immediately followed by a `<np>\n` string
- `.*`: matches any number of any character
- `/`: stops the search pattern / starts the replace pattern
- `$1`: replaces with the captured group
- `/`: stops the replace pattern / starts the modifiers
- `s`: asserts to treat the input string as a single line, forcing `.` to also match newline characters

Sample output:

```bsh
~/tmp$ cat inputfile
13.2000000000     , 3*0.00000000000       ,  11.6500000000     , 3*0.00000000000       ,  17.8800000000

Blablabla

  SATELLITE EPHEMERIS
     ===================
Output frame: Mean of J2000

       Epoch                  A            E            I           RA           AofP          TA      Flight Ang
*****************************************************************************************************************
2012/10/01 00:00:00.000     6998.239     0.001233     97.95558     77.41733     89.98551    290.75808    359.93398
2012/10/01 00:05:00.000     6993.163     0.001168     97.95869     77.41920    124.72698    274.57362    359.93327
2012/10/01 00:10:00.000     6987.347     0.001004     97.96219     77.42327    170.94020    246.92395    359.94706
2012/10/01 00:15:00.000     6983.173     0.000893     97.96468     77.42930    224.76158    211.67042    359.97311
 <np>
 ----------------
 Predicted Orbit:
 ----------------

 Blablabla
~/tmp$ < inputfile perl -0777 -pe 's/.*[*]+\n(.*) <np>\n.*/$1/s'
2012/10/01 00:00:00.000     6998.239     0.001233     97.95558     77.41733     89.98551    290.75808    359.93398
2012/10/01 00:05:00.000     6993.163     0.001168     97.95869     77.41920    124.72698    274.57362    359.93327
2012/10/01 00:10:00.000     6987.347     0.001004     97.96219     77.42327    170.94020    246.92395    359.94706
2012/10/01 00:15:00.000     6983.173     0.000893     97.96468     77.42930    224.76158    211.67042    359.97311
~/tmp$
```

### Original version:

Using Perl:

```
< inputfile perl -0777 -pe 's/.*[*]{3}\n(.*\n)\n.*/$1/s' > outputfile
```

- `< inputfile`: redirects the content of `inputfile` to `perl`'s `stdin`
- `-0777`: forces Perl to slurp the whole file at once instead of line by line
- `-p`: forces Perl to print the lines
- `-e`: forces Perl to read a line of program from the arguments
- `> outputfile`: redirects the content of `perl`'s `stdout` to `outputfile`

**Regex breakdown**:

- `s`: asserts to perform a substitution
- `/`: starts the search pattern
- `.*[*]{3}\n`: matches any number of any character up to the end of a `***\n` string
- `(.*\n)\n`: matches and groups any number of any character up to a newline character immediately followed by a newline character
- `.*`: matches any number of any character
- `/`: stops the search pattern / starts the replace pattern
- `$1`: replaces with the captured group
- `/`: stops the replace pattern / starts the modifiers
- `s`: asserts to treat the input string as a single line, forcing `.` to also match newline characters

Sample output:

```bsh
~/tmp$ cat inputfile
blablabla
blablabla
***
thingsIwantToRead1
thingsIwantToRead2
thingsIwantToRead3

blablabla
blablabla
~/tmp$ < inputfile perl -0777 -pe 's/.*[*]{3}\n(.*\n)\n.*/$1/s'
thingsIwantToRead1
thingsIwantToRead2
thingsIwantToRead3
~/tmp$
```

Comment: Does this handle the sample data provided?

Comment: @mikeserv Yes, I've added a sample output of the command

Comment: Hmmm... That doesn't look like the sample I see... Oh, I guess it is still here in the question. The op edited to provide a more accurately representative sample. Have you tried it there?

Comment: @mikeserv No I didn't, I actually didn't even notice that the question was updated (I have left this open for a while before answering). It won't work on the updated input file, so I'm editing it accordingly, thanks

Comment: Is the `\n(.*)` greedy? Will it not edit out all but the *last* occurrence of a matching paragraph? Or, I guess that should be, will it *include* everything between paragraph 1 and 2 if there are two possible matches for `*[*]*\n(.*)\n<np>`?

Comment: @mikeserv Hm, I'm having troubles understanding. It will match only the last occurence of the target pattern if there are multiple possible matches. This however doesn't seem to be likely to happen, at least judging from the sample input

Comment: @mikeserv However [I asked OP about this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208667/extract-paragraph-separated-with-using-awk/208769?noredirect=1#comment352879_208667)

Comment: Yeah - I'm unclear on that too - the question just really did a 180. I guess I'm still holding onto my initial impression from first reading it - which was how to print only a paragraph in a file following a unique marker. I ask though because it looks like `*[*]\n` matches the first occurrence of that string in input and `(.*)` matches everything up to the *last* `\n<np>`. And so if there *were* two - would it not get *`paragraph1 <np> middle junk \*\*\* paragraph2`*? I'm useless with w/ `perl` by the way, and so I really honestly curious.

Comment: @mikeserv Perl is greedy by default, and in my experience specifying an exact pattern after a greedy pattern (say `.*`) will match until the last occurence of the specified pattern and continue matching from there, so in this case the `.*` at the start itself will match until the last occurence of `[*]+\n`, in fact it will only print the last `*` separated section, and `(.*)` will match until the last occurence of `<np>\n`, which is (presumably) going to be only one per each `*` separated section

Comment: @mikeserv However [I asked OP about this also](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208667/extract-paragraph-separated-with-using-awk/208769?noredirect=1#comment352892_208667)

Comment: Oh, yeah - i didn't notice the leading `.*` - so, yeah, that squeezes it down to the last match.